Calling a subgraph from a supergraph and passing in the Upload scalar type causes me grief
TL;DR
When calling the supergraph to upload files where the type is defined as Upload in the schema, the subsequent call to the subgraph passing in the Upload type fails with: "message": "map[string]interface {} is not an Upload". Calling the subgraph directly works fine
Long version:
I have a simple apollo supergraph (gateway) in node:
require("./open-telemetry");
const { ApolloServer } = require("@apollo/server");
const { expressMiddleware } = require("@apollo/server/express4");
const { ApolloGateway, RemoteGraphQLDataSource } = require("@apollo/gateway");
const { graphqlUploadExpress } = require("graphql-upload");
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const args = require("yargs").argv;
const { readFileSync } = require("fs");

let svrPort = 4013;
if ("port" in args) {
  if (Number.isInteger(args.port)) {
    svrPort = parseInt(args.port);
  }
}
let schemaPath = "./supergraph-schema.graphql";
if ("local" in args) {
  if (typeof args.local === "string") {
    schemaPath = args.local;
  }
}

const supergraphSdl = readFileSync(schemaPath).toString();

class MyGraphQLDataSource extends RemoteGraphQLDataSource {
  willSendRequest({ request, context }) {
    // Ensure CSRF headers are set
    request.http.headers.set("apollo-require-preflight", "true");
  }

  didReceiveResponse({ response }) {
    // Log the response for debugging
    console.log("Response from subgraph:", response);
    return response;
  }
}

const gateway = new ApolloGateway({
  supergraphSdl,
  buildService({ url }) {
    return new MyGraphQLDataSource({ url });
  },
});

const server = new ApolloServer({
  gateway,
  csrfPrevention: true,
  context: ({ req }) => ({ req }),
  subscriptions: false,
  // Basic Healthcheck
  onHealthCheck: () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      resolve();
    });
  },
  uploads: false, // Disable built-in upload handling to use graphql-upload
});

async function startServer() {
  const app = express();

  // Use graphqlUploadExpress middleware
  app.use(graphqlUploadExpress());
  app.use(cors());
  app.use(bodyParser.json());

  await server.start(); // Await server start before applying middleware

  app.use(
    "/graphql",
    expressMiddleware(server, {
      context: async ({ req }) => ({ req }),
    })
  );

  app.listen(svrPort, () => {
    console.log(` Server ready at http://localhost:${svrPort}/graphql`);
  });
}

startServer().catch((err) => {
  console.error("Server failed to start", err);
});

// Generate supergraph with: npx -p @apollo/rover rover supergraph compose --config ./localsupergraph.yaml > local-supergraph-schema.graphql
// Run with: node gateway.js --local=./local-supergraph-schema.graphql

This gets called from a front end react component which sends a mutation which in turn constructs a POST request with a multipart form in the format required.
This ends up in the supergraph fine (and also in the subgraph fine if i call that directly) but the issue is when the supergraph calls the subgraph with the already parsed form data passing in the Upload type with the query. The subgraph errors with this message:
"message": "map[string]interface {} is not an Upload"

I can inspect the request in willSendRequest and all seems ok there, the correct query with the correct variables are present and the multipart form with the file has correctly been parsed to an Upload.
The subgraph is written in Go using 99designs gqlgen. Inspecting the body of the request in the handler in Go shows that apollo is sending a json body request and not a multipart form. The json looks like this for the file input:
"variables":{"input":{"file":{"promise":{},"file":{"filename":"my-image.png","mimetype":"image/png","encoding":"7bit"}}

What are my options here, is there some sort of config i'm missing in the node apollo supergraph? I have tried actually re-writing the query into a multi-part form using the request data in the process method but had different issues in Go with unexpected EOF errors reading the body! Also considering just adding an upload endpoint which in turn can upload to s3, send me the url back and then use that in my mutation instead of a physical file.
Any help or suggestions greatly appreciated!
